# Javascript return and map to an object

Tags: javascript, object, dictionary, mapreduce

I've an object that I would like to return two value and map them into 1 object.

**Object**

```
Itemlist:[
{name: 'Chicken', searchParam: 'chicken', search: true},
{name: 'table', searchParam: 'table', search: false},
{name: 'books', searchParam: 'books', search: true}]
```

Would like to return from Itemlist searchParam and search and map to an object that a result would be:

```
{chicken: true},{table: false},{books: true},
```

**So return would be something like**

```
{ Itemlist[0].searchParam :Itemlist[0].search }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `array#map` to get an array of object which contains `name` and `search` value from each object of itemlist.

```js
var itemlist = [{name: 'Chicken', searchParam: 'chicken', search: true},{name: 'table', searchParam: 'table', search: false},{name: 'books', searchParam: 'books', search: true}];

var result = itemlist.map(({searchParam, search}) => ({[searchParam]: search}));
console.log(result);
```

**ES5 Code :**

```js
var itemlist = [{name: 'Chicken', searchParam: 'chicken', search: true},{name: 'table', searchParam: 'table', search: false},{name: 'books', searchParam: 'books', search: true}];

var result = itemlist.map(function(item) {
  var obj = {};
  obj[item.searchParam] = item.search;
  return obj;
});
console.log(result);
```

Comment: That would require an ES6 transpiler

Comment: @jordiburgos  `That would require an ES6 transpiler`, no it doesn't.  Most modern browsers are now ES6..  If you need to target rubbish browsers, that's a different issue.  ES6, should now be regarded as the norm.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```js
let arr = [
{name: 'Chicken', searchParam: 'chicken', search: true},
{name: 'table', searchParam: 'table', search: false},
{name: 'books', searchParam: 'books', search: true}];


let result = arr.reduce((a, b) => {
    let prop = b.searchParam;
    a[prop] = b.search;
    return a;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: I made into one line:

a[b.searchParams] = b.search;
        return a;

Comment: `I made into one line`, if you want things short then `var result  = Itemlist.reduce((a,b) => (a[b.searchParam]=b.search,a), {})`

Comment: Note that the result is different from what the question states.

Comment: and if you like one-liners, it's `Object.assign(...arr.map(x => ({[x.searchParam]: x.search})))`

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new object, then assign the properties with the [] syntax

```
var result = {};
result[Itemlist[0].searchParam] = Itemlist[0].search;
return result;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var itemlist = [{
    name: 'Chicken',
    searchParam: 'chicken',
    search: true
}, {
    name: 'table',
    searchParam: 'table',
    search: false
}, {
    name: 'books',
    searchParam: 'books',
    search: true
}];

var list = itemlist.map(function(item){
   return {[item['name']] : item.search}
  });

console.log(list);
```